# Problems of time zones "ZE8", How to convert NSDate to NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

How to convert **(12/27/2013 05:49:41 PM ZE8)** NSString to NSDate?

```
NSString *string = @"12/27/2013 05:49:41 PM ZE8";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"];
NSDate *publishDate = [formatter dateFromString:string];
```

publishDate is getting null value. What is issue that?

Comment: really just some advice: don't write class names or variables or types or methods in CAPS -- CAPS ARE FOR CONSTANTS

Comment: setDateFormat: does NOT correspond to the string date. Change h:mm:ss to HH:mm:ss

Comment: @Daij-Djan Done clean CAPS methods. Getting company.publiishdate is null value. :(

Comment: @SavaMazăre coded '[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@“MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"];' But Getting company.publiishdate is null value. :(. **12/27/2013 05:49:41 PM EST** date will get company.publiishdate value. But **12/27/2013 05:49:41 PM ZE8** not get.

Comment: As @Kuba said, "ZE8" is invalid. I IS a valid time label on other systems, but not suitable for NSDateFormetter.

Comment: @SavaMazăre Yes, Kuba say is correct. Plz show me code that how to covert to RFC822.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears because `ZE8` format is **NOT** valid format for timezones in unix systems!

You can use:

- Localized GMT strings (and variance of that)
- RFC 822 GMT
- even Generic location format

But ZE8 is invalid

You have to convert this data to valid one, so you have to add another Array/table/dictionary what do you like with this values http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-keeping_time/side1.html and convert it to `RFC 822` for example

No, there is no built in way - you have to write this structure by yourself. For example using dictionary (if i were you i will write a category by myself). I write a simple solution for you, of course if you do this often you should keep this dictionary somewhere and also write all the values from above page (i write only two):

```
-(void)myBaseMethod {
    NSDate *finalDate = [self convertStringToDate:@"12/27/2013 05:49:41 PM ZE8"];
}

-(NSDate*)convertStringToDate:(NSString*)str {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"];
    return [formatter dateFromString:[self changeTimeZoneToValidOneFromString:str]];
}

-(NSString*)changeTimeZoneToValidOneFromString:(NSString*)inputStrDate {
    NSDictionary *timeZonesDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"GMT-08:00",@"ZE8",
                                  @"GMT-7:00",@"ZE7",
                                  nil];
    NSMutableArray *dateItems = [[inputStrDate componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy]; //in here I break the original string into array of strings (every element is separate date component)
    NSString *timeZoneString = [timeZonesDic objectForKey:[dateItems lastObject]]; //convert using dictionary
    [dateItems replaceObjectAtIndex:([dateItems count]-1) withObject:timeZoneString]; //replacing the last object of the existing array.
    return [dateItems componentsJoinedByString:@" "]; //in here I join it back together
}
```

Really make a `Category` (`NSDate`) for it, then you will be call only `convertStringToDate:` method and the rest will be in one place.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for replay it. Could u show me example of convert to RFC822?

Comment: Since iOS and all unix system does not understand this timezone format, there is no build way of doing this - i've edit my answer. This should works for you.

Comment: @Kuba, it looks like a regular search-and-replace, rather than a timezone conversion. It might be good for User3138941 though.

Comment: @SavaMazăre AFAIK you can't do this another way, because there is no support for this simply time labels.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, Issue is fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

//Optionally for time zone converstions
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];

NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myNSDateInstance];

[formatter release];
```

All the best